# use replaceAll and regex in android for extract a number in string

Tags: android, regex, extract, replaceall

i want extract a number from a long string
my code is :

```
      private String[] icons;
  private String[] pages;
            icons=geticons.split(";");
            pages=article.split(";");
            int i=0;
            for (String page:pages)
            {
                pages[i].replaceAll("(image)([0-9])", icons[$2]);
                i++;
       }
```

but icons[$2] error.
how to sovle it.

example :
elements of icons :

```
{"yahoo.com/logo.jpg" , "yahoo.com/logo3.jpg", "yahoo.com/logo8.jpg"}
```

elements of pages :

```
"hello how image0 ar you? where image3 are you? image8"
```

output :

```
"hello how yahoo.com/logo.jpg  ar you? where yahoo.com/logo3.jpg are you? yahoo.com/logo8.jpg"
```

Comment: why do you use a '$' sign? in java you access elements of an array like so: `icons[2]`. or did i miss something?

Comment: i want access to ([0-9]) and use it for access element of an array?

Comment: why don't you use `i` as index?

Comment: i have a string for example "hello how are you image0 where are you image2" i want replace url & number of image with image+nmber so i want to understand it

Comment: you should add one or two examples to your question, with your input and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your for loop makes no sense. Either use *i*, or omit it completely:

```
 for (String page:pages) {
      page.replaceAll("(image)([0-9])", icons[2]);
  }
```

Secondly, elements in the array in java are accessed directly by index:

```
arr[index]
```

In your case, that would `be icons[2]`

Finally, your regular expression will take into account only one digit in image name. So if you have image10 for example, it will not be correctly recognized. I would use:

```
"(image)([0-9]+)"
```

because + quantifier means "one or more times". Plus, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\\d` which denotes digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(image)([0-9]+)");

for(int i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pages[i]);
    while(matcher.find()) {

        String imageNumber = matcher.group(2); // I guess this is what you wanted to get with '$2'
        int n = Integer.parseInt(imageNumber);
        pages[i] = pages[i].replace(matcher.group(0), icons[n]);
    }
}
```